# Ping an editor for repeated invalid editing behavior

Tags: discussion, edits

[A certain new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4022747/17coder?tab=activity) is repeatingly changing posts and adding `>` to posts, changing them into a long "quote" block. So far, all of his previously accepted edits have been approved (strangely enough, some of them by the OP) and subsequently rolled back or re-edited by other users.
This particular user had 13 edits approved and 21 rejected; they all were the same ("improved formatting", huh!).

There seems no way to ping such a user and ask to **stop doing this**. Directly asking him to do so may be a useful option. Comments?

Comment: I only looked back through the most recent 15 or so, but it looks like a vast majority of the approvals were 1-vote approvals from the OP, who usually only has 1-rep point and probably has no idea what he/she is doing.

Comment: And it looks like his [only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038839/knowing-about-sticky-intent-in-andorid/26039069#26039069) is an exact copy and paste.  He did link to the answer, but didn't offer any citation or give credit beyond the link.

Comment: @psubsee2003: "the vast minority", nah, this only occurred 3 or so times. I find a lot of approvals for this *highly visible* bad edit from >2,000 rep users -- even up to 2 at >5,000.

Comment: I meant for this specific user, every of his approved edits were approved by the OP.

Comment: @psubsee2003: well ... I meant the approval votes *in general*, whether or not the edit was finally approved; such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5771095) from a +5,000 user.

Comment: So this guy is STILL doing these edits despite saying he won't Isn't it time for some more punitive action? And how are these edits getting approved? I count 17 that have been approved (and now rolled back)...

Comment: Despite earlier responses, he seems incorrigable. Also Not Good: at least >33K user *approved* this edit ... Can and *should* we extend punishing to include those who approve these kind of edits?

Comment: @Jongware Yes, though "punishment" seems hard. I would say that the same way a user can lose their ability to suggest edits, users should be able to be banned from moderating the edit queue. Whether that ban is time-based or indefinite, or triggered automatically/by an admin is up for debate, but we need some way of discouraging bad edit reviewers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If their suggestions are getting approved (and - sadly - some were), you can `@username` them in the comments. You'll have to write username by hand, it won't auto-complete as normally, but the notification will still go through.

Your other option would be to cast a custom moderator flag on one of the posts they edited. If you do that, try to be as specific as possible (and don't forget to note it's repeating behaviour). Moderators are used to check the actual post for issues when responding to flags and they might miss something that's buried in the revision history.

Comment: That first option is a nice (hidden) feature! So all I have to do is wait for the next edit (shouldn't take too long) and use "Custom reason"?

Comment: @Jongware I left them a comment in one of the posts they edited. Coincidentally, you rolled back that edit, so I've also left a comment for you there, to showcase the "editors get notified of `@username` comments" thingy. Hopefully we won't need to bother a mod, but if they continue "improving formatting" then you should probably flag.

Comment: Got it- I took your answer as @pinging in the "Reject" comment box, but now I see what you mean.

Comment: @Jongware [I left a comment on an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313695/how-to-add-placeholder-for-my-form-xml-fields-in-joomla?noredirect=1#comment41293838_26313695) I caught in the act (that was approved by the OP before rejected).  I probably could have been more diplomatic, but my comment actually did get a reply.  And from reading it, he has no clue and doesn't look like he will stop

Comment: @Jongware: Just an additional note. If the username has a space (like user[space]name), it has to be stripped before doing `@username`. Also be careful not to get into an argument with such users (which might typically happen in most cases). One comment and if not stopped then the Other flag as Yannis has mentioned.

Comment: @Harry I've always wondered what the correct syntax was when trying to do it manually. Thanks Harry