# How to know which edits were rejected?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I usually make 10 to 15 edits per day on non-regular bases. Most of the time, 1 or 2 edits get rejected. I always check the rejected edits in order to know what made them rejected and keep those things in mind when editing next times. But actually, there is no proper way to check which edits were rejected. All I have to do is to open all the edits that I made on a one particular day, on multiple tabs, go through each of them and check manually which one got rejected.

[image: Like this]

Shouldn't there be a nicer way to know about it? Perhaps, a slight-red background color on rejected edits and a slight-green or no color background for approved edits.

Comment: @cVplZ: not a *real* duplicate, this is a request for a better UI. With which, come to think of it, I agree.

Comment: It may also be useful quickly reviewing the [bad habits of certain editors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273268/ping-an-editor-for-repeated-invalid-editing-behavior) (yes folks, after suspension [he's at it again](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4022747/17coder?tab=activity))

Comment: @jongware: Perhaps that guy can be set up as a review audit...  He finds more reviewers that deserve banning than anyone else I know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has [now been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244941). Each suggested edit should be listed as one of approved, rejected, or pending.

> [image: How It Looks]

Here is a [direct link to your suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) that can be found under Profile > Activities > Suggestions from your user profile page.

Answer (score 22):

There used to be a [userscript on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3684/suggestion-status-a-userscript-to-view-the-status-of-your-suggested-edits) to do this, but the link died and the author hasn't put it back up. If anyone wants to track them down and ask them to rehost it, that would be nice.

Comment: Author of the userscript here. I've found back an older version of the script, but unfortunately I've not gotten it to work yet. StackExchange has changed somewhat since I wrote it and I'm not getting very helpful error messages, so it will take some time to debug.

If I can get it working, I will put it back up.

Comment: Haven't been able to fix the script entirely, but I've put up a gist in case somebody else wants to give it a try: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275536/1419007

Answer (score 15):

I'm the author of the userscript mentioned by [@Scimonster](/a/275399/1419007). I've spend a few hours trying to get the script working, but no luck.

[I've put the script online here](https://gist.github.com/1k777/d5f6dac87c7a81bf0722), so if you can get it working, please do.

Answer (score 7):

You could run a query through data.stackexchange.com.

For example, the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/239407/status-of-my-suggested-edits):

```
SELECT 
  'site://suggested-edits/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id)+'|Suggested Edit #'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id) [Suggested Edit Link], 
  PostId as [Post Link],
  Comment,
  CreationDate,
  CASE
    WHEN ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Approved'
    WHEN RejectionDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Rejected'
    ELSE 'TBD'
    END as Status
FROM SuggestedEdits 
WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
ORDER By CreationDate DESC
```

Lists the suggested edits for a specific user and shows if the edits were approved or rejected.

Answer (score 3):

I found these two links in another meta post earlier today:

[My Rejected Edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits)

[My Accepted Edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45756/my-accepted-edits)

You'll need to enter your user id in the field at the bottom of the post and then hit run query.

Comment: It works quite well. But how can I request this feature to be added in SO?

Comment: @ArslanAli You already have via this meta post. :) That's what the feature-request tag is all about: Requesting features. So long as it doesn't have a "status-declined" tag added, there is a chance the SE team will see it and say "Yes." And even after a declined tag, there is still a chance they'll go back and take another look.

Comment: Thanks @Kendra. I'm new to meta, I didn't know it before.

Comment: @ArslanAli It's cool- Though if you want to further your knowledge of how Meta works, [feel free to check out this FAQ post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) and read through the answers there. I've found it a nice reference myself. :) Or you can just browse the questions here and see how things are handled.