# Is there an easy way to see which of my edits were rejected?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Apparently, [the UI was worse before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275397/how-to-know-which-edits-were-rejected). But it's still not easy to see which of my edits were rejected, especially when there's 18 pages of edits in all.

I wish it was more like the UI for my flags. Just look at it:

```
Your flagging history

142 post flags
--------------------------
13  waiting for review
94  helpful
2   declined
6   disputed
27  aged away

31  comment flags
--------------------------
31  helpful

1   spam flags
--------------------------
1   helpful
```

I can see the two declined post flags by clicking on `declined`. I want (well, I wanted it mostly when I was <2k) this for suggested edits.

Comment: A filter on the "all actions > suggestions" page would be nice indeed.