# Tag only edit robo approved?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33868491/revisions

Take a look at revision two of the question. That was done by a sub 2k user, and approved unilaterally by 3 reviewers.

Now, you can see the post had a ton of problems left in this case. I was under the impression that tag-only edits are strongly discouraged, yet this was unilaterally accepted.

Now im unprivy to the selection process for audits for the suggested reviews queue, but is there some way to "contest" a suggested edit review that was approved?

Comment: "Every relevant edit is a good edit", so no, there's nothing you can do about this but @notify the editor if they pretty please with sugar on top want to look at the entire post and see what they can improve...

Comment: See (my own :P) [Ping a bad editor..](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273268/2564301) – but please make sure to tailor your message to the circumstances. In this case, you could use @CodeCaster's wording. Too bad you cannot `@ping` the approvers as well.

Comment: Somebody that spells "purelly" surely ought not consider editing spelling and grammatical mistakes.  He didn't.  This doesn't have anything to do with audits.  Probably best to stop looking for stone tablets and a police force to enforce their chiseled rules, SO users apply common sense.

Comment: Also what @Hans said (and what I was editing into my comment when I got called away): please consider that the editor isn't fluent in English enough to trust themselves to edit the entire post. The tag edit, while excruciatingly minimal, is relevant.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was under the impression that edits that do not adress all misgivings of a post are strongly discouraged, especially those who are done by users that get rep from it.

Comment: @Magisch discouraged is not a hard "you don't ever" ;) The rule applies to people who can follow it, I'd say. If your English is Engrish, don't do spelling edits. Its just common sense.

Comment: This isn't actually the worst tag only edit I've seen.  There is some obvious other stuff that needs fixing but not too much.

Comment: "approved unilaterally by 3 reviewers" Just FYI, the "uni" in "unilaterally" means 1, so three reviewers cannot do anything "unilaterally". "Trilaterally", perhaps, although I would say that removing the adverb altogether would be sufficient to make your case ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan im sorry im not that good in english I assumed unilaterally meant "in complete agreement" or something similar.