# Editing non functional code into .. non functional code. Editor seems unaware of the language syntax

Tags: discussion, edits, code

A user has attempted to improve some answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742632/4230591), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742298/4230591)) by editing their code. Before the editing took place, the code wouldn't work (e.g. it would raise IndentationError) or wouldn't be formated as code at all.

After the edit, the code still does not work because the indentation is incorrect.

No harm was done through *those* edits (I haven't checked all his python edits), but it could have an effect if a user messes up existing indentation because he wasn't aware that Python indentation is meaningful to the compiler and not just a matter of style.

It could also be harmful if for example a python beginner posts incorrectly indented code, and the editor changes it thinking it doesn't matter.

---

Should a custom flag be raised when a user's code-edits indicate he is unaware of the specific language details, so that a mod can investigate further and/or the user is notified?

Comment: So, what should this editor have done? Left unformatted code blocks alone because he doesn't know the language? Knowing the language is not a requirement for pressing Ctrl+K. The person who posted the answer should have done it, but because they didn't, Robert has done it for them. **It's not his fault their answer still sucks.**

Comment: @CodyGray Did you check all his code edits? Where they all non-harmful? I haven't checked them. Should they be checked? Should I notify a mod through flagging so that he takes a faster/more thorough look than me?

Comment: @CodyGray "So, what should this editor have done? Left unformatted code blocks alone because he doesn't know the language?" - Yes

Comment: Completely wrong. Even if the code doesn't compile in its current state because the indentation is wrong, it is a massive step forward from where the posts *originally* were, [with a bunch of random words that didn't even look like code because they were incorrectly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35742632/1). At least now, someone who *does* know the language can come back and fix the indentation. Honestly, the only other option than the community editing these answers is for them to just be deleted outright.

Comment: @CodyGray The reason I asked this question was because I have no fast way of checking the user's edits on _python code_. For example if a new python programmer pastes code (in non-code format) and an editor arbitrarily "fixes" the code (with arbitrary indentation), it would cause a big waste of time for everyone involved. In this case, leaving the code unformated would be completely right.

Comment: I'd say as long as ONLY code formatting was added - it is ok, because there's no harm to original post. Those particular edits are bad not because of that, but because they also destroy original meaningful formatting inside code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for [`user:1116757 [python]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1116757+%5Bpython%5D) show zero results, which indeed may be a good reason to assume this person does not know about its intricacies.

The [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76f337e1-de7b-4160-a410-d0b22a6fdbc1/view-source) shows that, even though the answerer did not use <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> shortcut, someone who is aware of Python's rules should have picked up on that and could have edited it correctly right away.
With the edit, the original indentation [got destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/caa9f126-ef36-4694-85c0-d8971f32e8e7/view-source).

Well meant as these edits (surely) are, maybe you should leave a @comment and ask him not to edit Python anymore.

The other example answer was, even in its original state, [bad enough to warrant a downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0e13c06d-48ae-48c3-8b6c-9db875cdff29/view-source).

Comment: Although i agree on most of what you said, i m not so sure leaving a comment on an edited answer would be the right course of action (it would be unrelated to the topic discussed, therefor noise, which is generally not good). Also, i don't think `@SomeUser` would notify the `SomeUser` (I might be wrong on that).

Comment: @Fermiparadox: it is possible to `@ping` any post editor: [Ping an editor for repeated invalid editing behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273268/2564301). And indeed it would not be useful to add this to another post, so just do so on one of your examples.

Comment: Oh I was wrong. Good to know `@ping` sends a notification. And, to my surprise, in the post you link there seems to be a strong agreement by community on using `@ping` to notify editors.