# Negative edit rollback - how to flag perpetrator?

Tags: discussion, edits

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819835/3181933) that was using an obvious car analogy with method namess such as Start(), IncreaseThrottle(), *Break()*, and OpenDoor().

As you're no doubt aware, "break" means to damage something, and a "brake" is used to stop a car, so it's clear that the method name here should have been Brake(). I understand that it's a little pedantic, but if I can do my part to improve an answer, even if it's on spelling, then I'm happy to do it.

What happened next was another user came in and [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/819835/12) my edit. While I doubt this was intentionally malicious, its effect is negative. After re-correcting my question, I looked for a way to flag this incorrect rollback but found there is none.

**Is there a way to flag "negative" rollbacks?** In this case, I doubt it was malicious, but in a situation where it is, there seems no way to bring to the attention of moderators. All I can do is e-mail the user using the address on their profile in an attempt to establish why it happened in the first place.

Comment: _Something a user of the car can make it do: Break()_ - Maybe the user works in the QA department ;)

Comment: @honk That's a fair point!

Comment: _"All I can do is e-mail the user"_ You can use a comment to @-ping any user who is in the revision list.

Comment: @josh Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I did try but the name prompt didn't pop up.

Comment: Yup, [that's expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273270/603977).

Comment: You can always use a custom flag if you see someone defacing a post.

Comment: I will admit that I rolled back @jhon's edit. Now that I see, I confused between what was already there and the edit. Will pay more attention next time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion:

1. In this instance, the difference is too pedantic to flag for a single rollback. Anyone can make a mistake in understanding. It certainly doesn't appear to be malicious.
2. Instead of re-editing, you should have just rolled it back again to your original edit. Then, if it was rolled back yet again, an auto-flag would have been generated.

   Personally, I'd have also left a comment to the editor (i.e. `@[the person who rolled back]`) and provided an explanation as to why what you wrote was correct, including the link to the definition which you provided in your second edit summary. The most likely issue is just a lack of understanding. It's also quite possible for any particular user that English isn't their first language, or even [just lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

   In other words, **assume good faith** and attempt to resolve the issue with the other user by engaging in communication. If you're truly adverse to engaging in communication with another user, even to the extent of just explaining why you made the change, then just assume good faith and wait to see if it's rolled back/edited a second time.
3. If, after you've rolled it back (and left a comment for the editor made the first rollback), the post gets rolled back (or edited with the same change) again, *then* raising a custom flag is reasonable.

#### If you really needed to flag

1. Just use a custom flag on the post where the issue occurred. Explain the issue.
2. In another situation, if you no longer have access to the post, or there is no associated post for the issue, but it is specific to an individual who has posts to which you have access, raise a custom flag on one of their other posts. Explain the issue; include a way for the moderator to find the post/edit/review/whatever that has the issue.
3. In another situation, where you don't have access to an associated post, nor another post by an associated user, raise a custom flag on one of your own posts. Explain the issue; include a way for the moderator to find the post/edit/review/whatever that has the issue.

Comment: Makyen, thank you for your detailed explanation. I kind of assumed that it was a mistake on Camilo's part, but didn't realise that I should rollback the rollback, and genuinely didn't know how best to handle these situations. Thank you for clearing things up for me.